# How to approve Stack App and log in to Stack Overflow using REST API?

Tags: support, api

I would like to create a small application just for me to log in to Stack Overflow and see my profile.

The issue is that if I understand the documentation correctly, I have to first approve my application for myself (optionally provide username/password if not logged in yet) and then every time I want to do something authenticated I have to go for access token to https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token where I have to provide my username and password in case I am not logged in.

Can this step be done automatically using REST API? So I don't have to manually pass username and password to the webpage?

I would like to provide username/password to my app (I have already approved my application in my profile) and then it would just post my username/password to verify that I have approved my app and get token automatically.

Is this possible?

Comment: As explained [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) you can request an access_token with the scope `no_expiry`. That should give you an access_token that you can use indefinitely.

Comment: @rene so does that mean that otherwise after approving app and getting a token with expiration 1 hour I would have to retype username/password to obtain a new token?

Comment: If the token is expired your users have to re-authenticate, yes.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be at [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)?